# why can't i get the value from post form, with get_post method php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I am trying to get data from a post form, but somehow the code is stopping, so that `$Title` doesn't gets a value, and the second alert doesn't kick in

```
if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('test');</script>";
    $Title  = get_post($conn, 'title'); 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$Title');</script>";
}
```

I expected the `$Title` to get the value from the form, and being alerted.
The code simply stop when it comes to $Title. it doesn't even leaves a error on chrome DevTool

Comment: Where is `get_post()` defined? What does that function look like?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `get_post()`, even if I knew what it did. It seems weird to me that you are supplying your `$conn` handle to a function that seemingly should just return the value of a POST variable.

Comment: $Title = $_POST['title'];

Comment: Are you using a framework that defines `get_post()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know get_post() is not a standard php function, unless if its  wordpress.

Try changing from

```
$Title  = get_post($conn, 'title');
```

to

```
$Title  = $_POST['title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i copied some code from another project, but forgot to copy this:

```
function get_post($conn, $var){
return $conn->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);}
```